# Повторное объявление переменной внутри статической функции

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

Никак не могу до конца понять один момент.
Вот обычная реализация Singleton:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Затем используем Singleton 2 раза:

```
Singleton *inst1 = [Singleton sharedInstance];
Singleton *inst2 = [Singleton sharedInstance];
```

Я правильно понимаю, что при повторном выполнении строки (во время второго вызова):

```
static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
```

Присвоения nil не произойдет, из-за того, переменная объявлена внутри статической функции? Т.е. при повторном вызове функции static строка будет просто проигнорирована?

Где можно почитать подробнее о такой ситуации? (объявление и инициализация переменных внутри статического метода)

Answer (score 1):

Вы правильно понимаете, что присвоения не произойдёт и строка будет проигнорирована. Однако это не потому что переменная объявлена внутри статического метода (строго говоря, в Objective-C вообще статических методов нет), а потому что эта переменная имеет модификатор static. Никакого отношения к Objective-C static не имеет, поэтому дополнительно почитать вы о нём можете в материалах по языку C, например, в стандарте.